# Solving for $a,b,c,d$ where $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 630^2$

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers, sums-of-squares

How could one solve for $a,b,c,d$ where:

$$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 630^2,\ a>b>c>d$$

$a,b,c,d$ squared is equal to the square of $630$, and $a$ is larger than $b$, and so forth.

$a,b,c,d$ is also of such form that:

$$n = x + (x+1) + (x+2) + (x+3), \ x\in\mathbb{N}$$

where $n$ could be substituted for $ a, b, c \ $or $d$.

In what ways could one attack this problem?

Comment: The latter condition is equivalent to saying all of a,b,c,d are congruent to $2\mod 4$, and so you can divide everything by $2$, replacing $630$ by $315$, and assume that all the variables are odd.  Then, $a$ is at least $\lceil{\frac{315}{2}}\rceil$.  From there, I would recommend considering the equation mod 3,5,7 (the divisors of 315) to see if there is anything useful you can extract.

Comment: Reducing modulo $8$ leads to a quick solution.

Comment: @Théophile Care to elaborate?

Comment: I do care to elaborate; please see answer below.

Comment: @JohnWO You should state that $ a = 4k+6$ directly, instead of saying that $a = k + (k+1) + (k+2) + (k+3)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Yes, although I think that making that simplification is part of the problem, i.e., realizing that one can get modular information from that constraint. In any case, a clearer way to write it in the problem would be something like this: "Also, $a,b,c,d$ are of the form $x + (x+1) + (x+2) + (x+3)$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$".

Answer (score 6):

Since $a, b, c, d$ are all of the form $4x+6$ for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$, we see that $a,b,c,d \equiv 2 \pmod 4$. It follows that $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2 \equiv 4+4+4+4 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$. However, $630^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 8$. Therefore there is no solution.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't understand the latter part of OP's question.

Comment: I have edited to explain why they are congruent to 2 modulo 4.

Answer (score 2):

I've asked the [Z3 solver](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/UMkQ) using the Python interface (a 2nd time ...):

```
a, b, c, d = Ints('a b c d')
ax, bx, cx, dx = Ints('ax bx cx dx')

solve(a*a + b*b + c*c + d*d == 630*630,
      a > b,
      b > c,
      c > d,
      a == 4*ax + 6,
      b == 4*bx + 6,
      c == 4*cx + 6,
      d == 4*dx + 6,
      show=True)
```

Solution:

```
timed out, probably no solution
```

Comment: Is this the unique solution? I'm wondering what happened to the case where they are even, since Lagrange 4 square theorem tells us there is a solution. Does the solution have repeated integers?

Comment: These do not satisfy the additional constraint that $a,b,c,d$ must be of the form $4x+6$.

Comment: Oh, that's what OP meant. That was a strange way of saying it.